# How do I make Unity 3D work on my Dell D2400 desktop?

Tags: unity, graphics, gnome, dell, 3d

On my 11.10-running desktop, Unity 2d seems to work, Unity 3d does not.  I ran a test, and here is what I got.

```
Not software rendered:    no  
Not blacklisted:          no  
GLX fbconfig:             yes  
GLX texture from pixmap:  no  
GL npot or rect textures: yes  
GL vertex program:        yes  
GL fragment program:      yes  
GL vertex buffer object:  yes  
GL framebuffer object:    yes  
GL version is 1.4+:       yes  

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

So, since I don't know much about what this means, can someone tell me what they mean, and how I can fix it (if I can).  I plan on replacing this computer (which is seven years old) next year, but in the meantime, can I have some help?  Also, with those results, can I run Gnome Shell?

PS: The code for the test was  /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specs I see about a D2400 it has an Intel i845 video driver, which I'm afraid isn't enough to run either Unity 3D or GNOME Shell.

- [Hardware Requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements)
- [Wiki page with more information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements)

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your window manager with Compiz using `compiz --replace`  it will start Unity 3D whether they like it or not.  On my Dell D820 which is also blacklisted, it runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your computer supports it then. I looked up the computer and it is an old model. I don't think Unity 3D will be supported on this machine